# iPOJO: difference between @ServiceProperty and @Property

Tags: java, osgi, ipojo

What's the difference between "service property" and "property" at http://felix.apache.org/site/how-to-use-ipojo-annotations.html#HowtouseiPOJOAnnotations-@ServiceProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A @ServiceProperty is published with the (OSGi) services provided by the component. On the other side, @Property are kept private.

For example:

```
@Component
@Provides
public class MyComponent implements MyService {

    @Property
    private String hidden;

    @ServiceProperty
    private String shown;

    [...]

}
```

This component publishes the MyService 'service' with the 'shown' property. 'hidden' is not published.

Comment: What if different services component provides need different properties? Is this unsupported?